# Probability that uniform random variables equal the natural numbers

Tags: probability-theory

I have random variables $X_{1}, X_{2}, \dots X_{n}$ that are each Unif$\{1, \dots, n\}$, and I want to calculate $$P(\{X_{1}, X_{2}, \dots X_{n}\}=\mathbb{N})$$

My intuition is that this means each $X_{n} = n$, which occurs with probability $\frac{1}{n!}$.

Does this seem correct?

Answer (score 2):

For each sample point $\omega$ the set $\{U_1(\omega),U_2(\omega),..., U_n(\omega)\}$ is a finite set and it cannot be equal to $\mathbb N$. So the probability is $0$.